# Android ImageButton not firing the onclick event, what is wrong with my code?

Tags: android

I have very simple code that includes ImageButton with OnClickListener that points to another Activity, the click on the ImageButton doesn't fire the onClick (The same problem was with Button) :

```
public class ToolsActivity extends Activity {
private ImageButton btnCamera;
final Context context = ToolsActivity.this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tools);
    this.btnCamera = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
    this.btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);  
        }
    }); 
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_tools, menu);
    return true;  
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp" >

  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:background="@drawable/btncamera"
      android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />
```

Comment: Are you sure the `onClick` callback isn't running? maybe your activity is just failing to start. Have you checked the logs or tried a debugger?

Comment: starting the MainActivity as the main works fine, I added other actions into the onClick but was the same result, debugger couldn't reach the onClick, very strange.

Comment: I had copied and pasted 2 buttons. Both of them had         android:layout_alignParentTop="true". I was adding on click only on the top one. Even though I could clearly see on the screen two button images, somehow they were overlapping on each other.

Answer (score 9):

I can't see anything wrong with the code. If it works with a regular button my guess is that you maybe have to set `android:clickable="true"` in the xml (you can also do it in code).

Answer (score 0):

I opened new Android project and copy paste may code, and it works, I guess something with the project was damaged.